# location.reload(true) without get variables/only called once

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers

I have a user profile page where they can change their profile picture. Cutting to the chase, the PHP uploads the new image, and redirects back to the profile page but the page remains with the old profile picture until a page refresh.

I’ve tried the meta tags and PHP headers so I need `location.reload(true)` to happen once, but how can I call it just once, and only after a profile picture change. (Using a get variable won’t work because I can’t find a way to remove it after the reload, so it reloads infinitely).

...or am I going about this a bad way?

**UPDATE: FIX**

Solved this problem by using `history.pushstate()` to remove the URL variable (refresh=1) before calling `location.reload(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax to load the url of the new image after it has been uploaded. 
So you fetch the url of the profile image always in background and after the new one has been uploaded, it can be reloaded from background.

Comment: I COULD except I’m using PHP to change the state of a button too, which wouldn’t then be update by the AJAX, for example in the input type=button’s value attribute, <?php if($imagelink == “”){echo “Add new profile picture”;}else{echo “Change profile picture”;} ?>

Comment: Unless of course you’re suggesting I change it with the JavaScript after the AJAX… but is that making it too complicated?

Comment: You have to give the button an id and add a function in your javascript which is called if the button is clicked. So you can handle the upload and then also update/replace the button label.

Comment: Perhaps you are not correctly updating the current image url in your database or however you are storing your data. I would suggest that you have your page with the upload field->select image->upload image->after upload finished redirect to the same page.

Comment: that’s how I am doing it. Image uploads correctly, as does the link. I know that because if I manually refresh the page, it’s fine :)

Comment: how the redirect works? you could force a reload redirect with a html meta tag. You submit the input for the file to a new page and from this one you could immediately redirect to the profile view.